# How do you clear the arp cache on linux?

Tags: arp

Both:

```
sudo ip -s -s neigh flush all
```

And:

```
sudo arp -d 192.168.0.102
```

Instead of clearing the arp cache they seem to just invalidate entries (they will appear as `incomplete`). Even after some minutes, the ARP cache looks like:

```
$ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.0.103                    (incomplete)                              eth0
192.168.0.1              ether   DE:AD:BE:EF:DE:AD   C                     eth0
```

(The MAC of the gateway has been refreshed - that is ok)

How can I *really* clear the ARP cache, like in "delete all entries from the table"? I **do not** want to keep incomplete entries, I want them removed. Is this possible?

### EDIT

This is my system:

```
» arp --version
net-tools 1.60
arp 1.88 (2001-04-04)
+I18N
AF: (inet) +UNIX +INET +INET6 +IPX +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +ATALK +ECONET +ROSE 
HW: (ether) +ETHER +ARC +SLIP +PPP +TUNNEL -TR +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +FR +ROSE +ASH +SIT +FDDI +HIPPI +HDLC/LAPB +EUI64 

» lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

» uname -a
Linux polyphemus.xxx-net 3.13.0-46-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 2 18:23:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Or more clearly, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Are you short of arp table entries? Maybe there's a program asking for that IP, thus renewing that entry. Check with `wireshark` or `tcpdump`.

Comment: @MichaelMartinez because [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  It seems likely that question isn't the root problem and there might be some underlying problem that the OP should be working on instead.

Comment: @EEAA: It is a bit long to explain. I am having troubles with my sip client in one of my routers, so I need to restore factory settings and reconfigure. For this I need to reconfigure my network topology, because restoring factory settings stops this router from playing nicely in my LAN. This happens often, and every time I have trouble locating the IP of the device. Since I am unable of tricking my DHCP server on giving fixed IPs, I have decided to create a personal mapping of MAC addresses to hostnames, so that I can automatically identify hosts by MAC, processing NMAP output.

Comment: For this I need first to manualy identify some important hosts by MAC address, but I am seeing too much rubbish in the ARP cache, which annoys me. So I want to clean it, but the clear operation does not do what it is supposed to do, which annoys me **way more**

Comment: @jeckyll2hide Please edit that information into your original answer, so more people can see it without digging into the comments.

Comment: The reason why this information is not in the question is because it is not relevant. I want a clean ARP cache. Full stop. You do not trust me that I want that, but that is your problem, not mine. I assure you: I want a clean ARP cache.

Comment: In case ARP (or the kernel?) does not support this (!), a simple "not possible" would suffice. Some rationale on "why" would be welcome.

Comment: There is an in-deep explanation of the ARP cache mechanism here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15511117/647991

Comment: I have the same problem (and the same reason: I want a clear ARP table, for OCD reasons if no other) and neither solution works.

Answer (score 15):

## Original oneliner

```
ip link set arp off dev eth0 ; ip link set arp on dev eth0
```

Be sure to do it all at once, so you don't break network connectivity before you're able to turn ARP back on.

## Interface discovering copy-paste command

```
interfaces=$(
  arp -n | awk '
    NR == 1 {next}
    {interfaces[$5]+=1}
    END {for (interface in interfaces){print(interface)}}
  '
);
for interface in $interfaces; do
  echo "Clearing ARP cache for $interface";
  sudo ip link set arp off dev $interface;
  sudo ip link set arp on  dev $interface;
done
```

*Note:* The semicolons allow you to condense this command into a oneliner, but it looks terrible in a code block on SO.

### Example output on Raspbian

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.0.0.1                 ether   58:19:f8:0d:57:aa   C                     wlan0
10.0.0.159               ether   88:e9:fe:84:82:c8   C                     wlan0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ interfaces=$( arp -n | awk ' NR == 1 {next} {interfaces[$5]+=1} END {for (interface in interfaces){print(interface)}} '); for interface in $interfaces; do echo "Clearing ARP cache for $interface"; sudo ip link set arp off dev $interface; sudo ip link set arp on  dev $interface; done
Clearing ARP cache for wlan0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.0.0.159               ether   88:e9:fe:84:82:c8   C                     wlan0
```

Comment: One must either do in a shell script or at the machine, as it seems to break the connectivity after the first command.

Comment: I did it on one line, and it worked: `dev=eth2; ip link set arp off dev $dev; sleep 1; ip link set arp on dev $dev`. The `sleep` may not be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Your first solution works, it just takes a little time (5-10 seconds in my test on Kali) to go from "(incomplete)" to no entries.

Presumably it is in some sort of transitional state on its way to being deleted.

Comment: For me (Ubuntu 14.04) this was not the case: the entries are kept for a long time (forever?) in the incomplete state. I will re-check this again today.

Comment: Verified: even after some minutes, the entries are still there, in the incomplete state (arp 1.88, net-tools 1.60)

Comment: Well then your issue is certainly non-standard behavior, maybe particular to Ubuntu 14.04.  The correct way for doing it in Linux is just not working for you.  Hope you find your answer soon.  Can delete this one if you'd like.

Comment: No, leave it, it gives info for others. But I guess that the more "standard" behavior is to be found in Ubuntu, not in Kali, which is a distro for penetration testing and has default values specifically tweaked for that use case.

Answer (score 5):

Your mentioned solution is the correct and safe approach to flush the ARP table:

`ip neigh flush all [dev <device>]`

If certain entries are changed into invalid, that's temporary and part of the ARP protocol. The important aspect is that the mapping is gone, an ARP entry flagged as incomplete is not an IP-MAC entry on the table.

I've just tried this and in my case it immediately cleared the table and left no incomplete entries.

Comment: In some (unclear) cases, ip neigh flush all is not sufficient. In my case it did not clear entries added with arp -s.

Comment: I much prefer this to my own answer above, with the added caveat regarding static ARP entries, depending on the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In certain system, `ip` command is not available.

```
user@linux:~$ ip
-bash: ip: command not found
user@linux:~$
```

So this the alternative of the `ip link set arp off dev eth0; ip link set arp on dev eth0` command.

If you want to delete all entries from the table in a single command, use `for loop` like the following example.

**BEFORE**

```
user@linux:~$ arp
? (10.0.0.1) at 00:00:00:aa:aa:12 [ether]  on eth1
? (172.168.0.3) at 00:00:00:aa:aa:11 [ether]  on eth2
user@linux:~$
```

**REMOVING ARP WITH ARP -D COMMAND**

```
user@linux:~$ for i in 10.0.0.1 172.168.0.3; do sudo arp -d $i; done
user@linux:~$
```

**AFTER: MAC ADDRESS REMOVED FROM THE ENTRIES WITH INCOMPLETE MESSAGE**

```
user@linux:~$ arp
? (10.0.0.1) at <incomplete>  on eth1
? (172.168.0.3) at <incomplete>  on eth2
user@linux:~$
```

That's true, by deleting arp with `arp -d` command, the arp entries are still there with `incomplete` message.

To solve this problem, use `ifconfig ethx up/down` like this

**BEFORE**

```
user@linux:~$ arp
? (10.0.0.1) at <incomplete>  on eth1
? (172.168.0.3) at <incomplete>  on eth2
user@linux:~$
```

**DISABLE & ENABLE THE INTERFACES ETH1 & ETH2 IN A SINGLE COMMAND**

```
user@linux:~$ for i in 1 2; do sudo ifconfig eth$i down; sudo ifconfig eth$i up; done
user@linux:~$
```

**TADAAA ... PROBLEM SOLVED :)**

```
user@linux:~$ arp
user@linux:~$
```